# How to add object without slug in the function

Tags: python, django

I want to add course.tutor.add(self.request.user) to the function below but don't know how to do that, because i don't know how to do without slug and so on

```
class FormWizardView(SessionWizardView):
template_name = 'courses/create_course.html'
file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'courses'))
form_list = (CourseForm1,CourseForm2,CourseForm3,CourseForm4)

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    instance = Course()
    for form in form_list:
        for field, value in form.cleaned_data.items():
            setattr(instance, field, value)
    instance.save()
    return redirect('courses:my_courses',username=self.request.user.username)
```

Comment: actually, `form`s have `.instance`, You don't need to iterate the field, value to get the data

Comment: can you explain that to me, i did everything in the done function to save data from fields, and exactly how to make course.tutor.add(self.request.user), i tried a lot of things but it gives me error, how to do that?